# Looping json_encoded data

Tags: javascript

Hey I have a json_encode which im trying to loop and display the output but its not working, i get no output =/

This is my js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z4jTc/1/

Can some one explain why it won't loop?

Code:

```
var messages = {"1":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing once"],"2":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing twice :)"]};

    for(var id in messages){

            var read = messages[id][0];
            var from = messages[id][1];
            var sent_on = messages[id][2];
            var content = messages[id][3];

            document.write = 'test';
            document.write = '<div class="message_info">';
            document.write =  '<b>From:</b> '+from+'<br/><br/>';
            document.write = '<b>Sent On:</b> '+sent_on;
            document.write = '</div><div class="message_content">';
            document.write = content;
            document.write = '</div> <br/><br/>';

    }​
```

Comment: Having a jsfiddle makes it so much easier to analyze the question. Good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many document.write's is pretty slow. You could do it in one call after you parse the object:

```
var messages = {"1":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing once"],"2":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing twice :)"]};
var output = [];
for(var id in messages){

    var read = messages[id][0];
    var from = messages[id][1];
    var sent_on = messages[id][2];
    var content = messages[id][3];

    output.push('test');
    output.push('<div class="message_info">');
    output.push( '<b>From:</b> '+from+'<br/><br/>');
    output.push('<b>Sent On:</b> '+sent_on);
    output.push('</div><div class="message_content">');
    output.push(content);
    output.push('</div> <br/><br/>');
}​

document.write(output.join(''));
```

...or place the output in a container on the page...

```
document.getElementById('destinationContainer').innerHTML(ouput.join(''));
```

Comment: oops... been using Jquery too much. The line should be:

document.getElementById("destinationContainer").innerHTML = output.join("");

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GoofyDawg/6N89H/

Answer (score 3):

You are constantly overwriting the `document.write` function, you are never actually calling it.

```
document.write("test");
```

is how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: does it have to be " " or can i use single quotes? Also do you mean that i can't use document write more than once so it all has to be in one document write?

Comment: You can use single quotes, the important thing is the parentheses instead of the `=`.

Comment: @Dave Any quotes are fine. You can call it multiple times, see http://jsfiddle.net/Z4jTc/2/. However, if call it again after the document has finished loading, it will replace the document contents entirely. Nobody really uses `document.write` nowadays, except for debugging. Stick with `innerHTML` for the node that you want to create content for

Comment: @Dave: don't just say it doesn't work. What is the wrong behavior? error message?

Comment: No error - just no output. The difference is its from an XHR with my ajax call? Wondering if that might cause some unknown effect

Answer (score 0):

`document.write`  is a function

Use

```
document.write('test');
```

Instead of

```
 document.write = 'test';
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Z4jTc/2/